# Taking out @XmlTransient creates 500 server error

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, entity, xmltransient

This is bugging me a lot. I understand that using @XmlTransient in a java entity excludes the relationship of the entity from the Json or Xml conversion in a web service e.g., RESTFul web service. **But sometime you need to include the relationship data** for example if you have a customer entity that has a one to one relation with an address entity. The getter for address in customer has the @XmlTransient by default but when i take it out to get the data from customer in a web service it gives me a 500 Internal server error.

Does anyone know how to get data from a relational entity in a web service without getting a 500 html error?

Please help...

Comment: corrected your tagging

Comment: Thanks though...